# Stored Procedure to send different email content to different contacts when it is 30 days before the finish date

Tags: sql-server-2008, email, stored-procedures

I need to create a stored procedure in my ms sql server management studio 2008 to send automated email to each email address in the table when it is 30 days before the 'finish date' showing the 'data' value of the same row as the email content. Sample table is as below. I am new to stored procedure, can you please help me with this? Thanks in advance. [image]

Comment: 1. Set up database mail http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/29060/SQL-SERVER-Configure-Database-Mail-Send-Email. 2. Write a select query (using the `GETDATE()` function that returns the dataset you want. 3. Implement this in a stored procedure and run it every day from SQL Agent. I can help in more detail, just post back. But make sure you configure database mail first

Comment: Thank you for your reply Nick. I have checked we have already set up the database mail. Can you please help me into details on the stored procedure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So this query picks out the data you want:

```
SELECT email, data
FROM YourTable
WHERE [finish date] = DATEADD(d,-30,CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE))
```

Here is a stored procedure that uses a cursor to go through those one by one and send an email. Run this in management studio to create the stored procedure.

After that use `uspSendEmails` to run it.

You can use a SQL Agent job to run this every day.

```
CREATE PROC uspSendEmails
BEGIN
-- variables to hold values for each row
DECLARE @email VARCHAR(50)
DECLARE @data VARCHAR(50)

-- declare the cursor
DECLARE cEmails CURSOR FOR  
SELECT email, data
FROM YourTable
WHERE [finish date] = DATEADD(d,-30,CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE))

-- Open the cursor and fetch first row
OPEN cEmails
FETCH NEXT FROM cEmails
INTO @email, @data


WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0   
BEGIN 

    -- Use database mail SP to send email
    EXEC sp_send_dbmail 
         @profile_name = 'Your mail profile',
         @recipients = @email,
         @subject = 'subject'
         @body=@data

    -- Get the next row
    FETCH NEXT FROM cEmails
    INTO @email, @data        
END

CLOSE cEmails
DEALLOCATE cEmails
END
```

Comment: Thanks you so much Nick. I will try it out in my database.